# AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'")

Tags: python, pandas, attributeerror

I am new to Python and I have been stuck on a problem for some time now. I recently installed the module `pandas` and at first, it worked fine. However, for some reason it keeps saying

> AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'").

I have looked all over StackOverflow and the consensus is that there is likely another file in my CWD with the same name but I believe I don't.

Even if I create a new project and call it, for example, `Firstproject.py`, and immediately `import pandas as pd`, I get the error.

I would appreciate the help. I can provide more info if required.

Comment: I suggest visiting [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in order to get a better insight on how to ask a solid question. Additionally, some code, errors, and a slightly better explanation is necessary in order for others to offer you help (they 1st need to understand what the issue). Hang in there. You'll be great at this.

Comment: Esketit... pls check answers given below if any of in the help.

Comment: [Edit] your Question and show the full **Traceback**

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is this:

The command

```
import pandas as pd
```

in your case didn't import the *genuine* pandas module, but some *other* one - and in that *other one* the `read_csv()` function *is not defined*.

**Highly likely you have in your project directory (or in your current directory) a file with the name "pandas.py"**.

And - highly likely - you called the `pd.read_csv()` function in it.

**Rename this file**, and you will be happy again. (Highly likely.)

Comment: Spot on "Highly likely you have in your project directory (or in your current directory) a file with the name "pandas.py"."

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to type "pandas" in your console, and you will be able to see where your "pandas" name is originated from:

```
>>> pandas
<module 'pandas' from '/some-path/site-packages/pandas/__init__.py'>
```

Answer (score 0):

There might be possibility that you are using this name for your script as `read_csv.py`  hence pandas itself confused what to import, if or `csv.py` then you can rename it to something else like `test_csv_read.py`.

also remove any files in the path naming `read_csv.pyc`  or `csv.pyc` .

Comment: Hey pygo this is not the case.

Comment: Hey pygo it happens even I use one line of code which is just to import pandas. ie. import pandas as pd

Comment: ill upload a screen shot?

Comment: @Esketit, sure  that will help

Comment: Sorry I cant it wont let me but i have this:                                            
Backend TkAgg is interactive backend. Turning interactive mode on.
AttributeError("module 'pandas' has no attribute 'read_csv'")
Stack trace:
 >  File "c:\users\(my name was here)\source\repos\what the hell\what the hell\what_the_hell.py", line 1, in <module>
 >    import pandas as pd
Loaded '__main__'
The program 'python.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution 
when you downloaded python its automatically download 32 you need to delete if you don't have 32 and go download 64 and then problem solved :)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had installed module "panda" instead of "pandas". I was getting this error, even when there was no conflicting .py files were present in working folder.

Then I recognized my mistake, and then installed package "panda**s** and problem got resolved.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to update pandas to a later version using the following command:

```
pip install --upgrade pandas
```

The read_xml function is only available in pandas versions >= 1.3.0.